# Using Linq To SQL to search for multiple strings in a field

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use Linq to SQL to search a text column for multiple matching words, but the query is not doing what I expect.

Here is my sample code:

```
            string[] nameSearch = new string[2];
            nameSearch[0] = "John";
            nameSearch[1] = "Doe";

            var customers = context.Customers.AsQueryable();
            foreach (string name in nameSearch)
            {
                customers = customers.Where(r => r.CustName.Contains(name));
            }
            Data.Customer[] results = customers.ToArray();
```

The query that runs is:

```
    SELECT [t0].[CustName]
    FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[CustName] LIKE @p0) AND ([t0].[CustName] LIKE @p1)
    -- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 5; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [%Doe%]
    -- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 5; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [%Doe%]
```

How do I fix this query?  (It's suppose to be searching for John and Doe, not Doe and Doe.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lambda expression is only evaluated when the query runs, i.e. during the call to `ToArray()`. By then, `name` is bound to the last item in your array.

You can use a local variable in your `foreach` loop in order to avoid referencing the outer `name` variable in your lambda expression:

```
var customers = context.Customers.AsQueryable();
for (string name in nameSearch) {
    string curName = name;
    customers = customers.Where(r => r.CustName.Contains(curName));
}
Data.Customer[] results = customers.ToArray();
```

Comment: Right, you don't want to capture the loop variable.

Answer (score 2):

#### The answer:

```
foreach (string name in nameSearch)
{
    string name_ = name;
    customers = customers.Where(r => r.CustName.Contains(name_));
}
```

#### The explanation:

The lambda function `r => r.CustName.Contains(name)` captures the `name` variable. This same variable is in scope for both iterations. Using a block-scope temporary breaks this link, so that each invocation of the lambda function picks up a different variable with a distinct value.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] nameSearch = new string[2];
nameSearch[0] = "John";
nameSearch[1] = "Doe";


var result = customers.Where(r => nameSearch.Contains(r.CustName));
```

Answer (score 0):

No the above is wrong, it will overwrite customers every time !

customers = customers.Where(r => r.CustName.Contains("John") && r.CustName.Contains("Doe"));

Comment: If, by "the above", you mean @Frédéric's or my answer (answers with the same vote are ordered randomly), then no, they aren't wrong. Each pass of the loop will replace the `customers` LINQ expression with a new expression that applies a `Where` clause to the original expression. It is a fairly stock-standard technique for building up complex queries.